# Calling one module method from another of the shared same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class:

```
class SpecialAwesome
  module Controller
    def builder
      SpecialAwesome.with_member(current_member)
```

which fails saying:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_member'
```

But then I see the method here at:

```
class SpecialAwesome
  module Options
    def with_member member
      self.class.new options.merge(:member => member)
    end
```

How come the other file doesn't recognize this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_member` is not `SpecialAwesome` class method, but it is defined in `Options` module. To make it work as you expect, you can for example use `extend` method:

```
class SpecialAwesome
  module Options
    # ...
  end
  extend Options
  # ...
end
```

which will add methods defined in `Options` module as `SpecialAwesome` class methods.

Comment: So I understand you correctly, am I to put `extend Options` directly after the Options module instantiation or should I put it in inside the Controller module?

Comment: @Trip If you want instance methods defined in `Options` module to be available as a `SpecialAwesome` class methods, you just need to call `extend` method with `SpecialAwesome::Options` as an argument on `SpecialAwesome` class. 
So another example is:
`SpecialAwesome.extend SpecialAwesome::Options`.

Answer (score 2):

The `with_member` method is defined as an instance method on `SpecialAwesome::Options`, not as a class method of `SpecialAwesome`. Probably, this is an issue.

Comment: `WhisperApi::Options.with_member` returns a noMethod Error as well.

Comment: Right, because with_member is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: @Trip it's because `with_member` is instance method, not class method.